Правильно ли стоят запятые в данном предложении? Если можно, ссылку на правило, пожалуйста
Особенно тронули слова брата о том, — и он не раз это подчеркнул, — что сильно нуждается во мне.

Правило известное: выбор запятых при обособлении вводных конструкций, пункт 4  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125  Но вызывает сомнение грамматика предложения. Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным, а это СПП с нерасчлененной структурой, и вряд ли можно использовать вставку между главной и придаточной частью.  В главной части только указательное слово О ТОМ, то есть непонятно, к каким именно словам относится вставка. У классиков такие варианты вроде бы не встречаются, но это надо уточнять.

Возможная правка: Особенно тронули слова брата о том, что он очень нуждается во мне, — не раз он это подчеркнул. Здесь присоединительная конструкция в конце предложения, то есть по сути та же вставка.

На Ваше усмотрение.
Я отдаю предпочтение единому знаку; можно рассматривать и как "симметрию" знаков.
У Вас все знаки расставлены правильно - здесь зап-тире рассматриваются как единый знак, выделяющий вставную конструкцию:

При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине предложения встречается
употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания: Вы садитесь
в коляску, – это так приятно после вагона , – и катите по степной
дороге (Ч.).
Такое выделение для современных текстов не характерно.
Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания следует
отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, необходимого по условиям
контекста: Жизненный материал – все то, что Достоевский называл
«подробностями текущей жизни» , – не изучают. Просто писатели живут <…
внутри этого материала (Пауст.); Называли фамилии мужей и братьев, – живы ли, здоровы ли они? – как будто этот военный мог знать по
именам все тысячи рабочих, дравшихся на всех фронтах (А. Т.).


В этом случае вам нужна одна запятая (после "том"). Вторая вам зачем? Вы разделили две грамматические основы. А вставная конструкция у вас обособляется при помощи двух тире и к запятым не имеет никакого отношения.
Если интересует, почему запятая перед, а не после вставной конструкции, то тут всё просто: она находится с той же стороны запятой, что и фраза, которую она поясняет.
А правило вам какое? У вас сложное предложение с разными конструкциями. Для каждой своё правило. А для их совмещения используют логику, опыт, здравый смысл и языковое чутьё.
